# Perforce about to integrate unchanged files

Tags: version-control, perforce

I use the P4V Windows client to integrate changes from my own branch to the main line. After resolving files, P4V still shows several files in the integration changelist, althought these files are identical on the two branches and I have never submitted them on my branch. When looking around and googling, I found some vague hints, for instance [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4800814/should-i-submit-unchanged-files-to-perforce), but having read these I still fail to understand what’s going on. Can you please point me in the right direction?

Comment: It's hard to answer without a few more details.  Can you run your example from the command line and include all the command output?

Comment: I've run it from the command line, there isn't a lot of information that would help. The integration operation lists the filenames it integrates, so does the resolve operation. However, all these suspicious files have version #1 on my branch ... something might have gone wrong when integrating from the main line to my branch earlier?

Answer (score 2):

It can be the case that independent edits made separately to both the branch line and the main line had identical content. Then, after integrating from the one line to the other, the result will have no differences, but it can still be useful to submit it, because it records for the future the fact that you've reviewed the changes and intentionally decided to include them in both lines.

When you resolved the file, the Perforce merge tools would have told you that the changes appeared in both codelines, but until you get practiced in using the merge and resolve tools, it can be hard to spot these indicators.

You'll probably want to study these docs to learn how to interpret all the information that P4V is showing you during your merge/resolve work: http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4v/merging_files.html

Comment: Thank you Bryan for the answer and the link. Nice try, but, as mentioned in my question, these are files I have never submitted (or even opened, as I far as I can remember) on my branch.